# PHP - Check a string and create a page structure from input

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a script for a page structure system where ideally the user enters in a page structure in a certain way and then the script outputs it in a slightly different way. It's very difficult to explain but what I want is for this;

> = Section 1
>
> Page 1
>
> Page 2
>
> = Section 2
>
> Page 1
>
> Page 2

To be turned into the following;

> Section 1\section-1||Page 1
>
> Section 1\section-1||Page 2
>
> Section 2\section-2||Page 1
>
> Section 2\section-2||Page 2

So essentially the input is formatted into a site structure that can be inserted into another system that can generate pages for a website. It's a long story but how can this be achieved? I'm not new to PHP but still very much at a junior/beginner level.

So each "section" is a category and of course each page... is a page. Any help please?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You've got a problem, how have you tried to solve it so far?

Comment: I really didn't know where to start. I thought I could do a foreach and did some research on the PHP site but the notes didn't help me for what I needed so I wasn't too sure.

Comment: Well, is the site structure already set, are you trying to parse a file with a format you can't control? You're going to want to parse the contents, identify Sections and pages within sections. You could read the file, line by line, check for a section (=) when you get a section add to an array, then continue until you find the end or another section.. just a suggestion, worth going trying to figure out?

Comment: Well using what @hek2mgl has put has nearly got me what I need. I'm sorry I can't explain it any further as it's quite a confusing question but I explained it as best as I could. I now just need to not have everything on a new line. It's the second line of their code where it explodes each line with "\n" which I'm assuming is making each line stay on one page instead of joining them together.

Comment: Play with the code that @hek2mgl gave you, then update your question with what you've worked with and where you're getting stuck. The explode will take the file as you had it and break it up into lines. Assuming \n was your separator and not \r\n

Comment: I just did what hek2mgl suggested. \r\n got everything to work and stay on one line. It looks like every line was remaining split (staying on a line by itself) and just need the \r there to fix it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little parser will do:

```
$sites = array();

// Split input by new lines.
foreach(preg_split( '/\r\n|\r|\n/', $input) as $line) {
    // Skip empty lines
    if(!trim($line)) {
        continue;
    }

    // Check for a section header (starts with a `=<space>`)
    if(strpos($line, '=') === 0) {
        $current = substr($line, 2); 
        $current .= '\\' . str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($current));
    } else {
        // Build site paths and add to the array
        $sites []= $current . "||$line";
    }
}

echo implode(PHP_EOL, $sites);
```

Output:

```
Section 1\section-1||Page 1
Section 1\section-1||Page 2
Section 2\section-2||Page 1
Section 2\section-2||Page 2
```

Comment: Works well thanks, however it outputs the following;

`Section1`
`section1`
`||Page 1`
`Section1`
`section1`
`||Page 2`

Comment: I'm using the standard textarea tag to collect the input, would that change any formatting at all?

Comment: Try using `\r\n` in the `explode` function

Comment: Ah perfect! The \r\n has put everything on one line now. Question answered, thanks a bunch hek2mgl :)

Comment: You are welcome. Need to get AFK for a while. Will enhance the solution to start working with both types of delimeters (as you can't choose which browser is used by the client)

Comment: Hm, I'm sending the page structure to a file and it's removing the backslashes :/ Any ideas for a fix perhaps? Googling just returns questions to remove them, which is what I don't want!

Comment: @Dan I've  edited my answer. Now it works with any type of newline character. About the missing slashes after saving to a file, I can only say: You are doing something wrong, as it should work flawlessly. But this would be a topic for a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out I had a strip slash before writing to the file. I'm looked over the code above and the code I have and can't figure out how to remove all line breaks because at the moment the structure is causing some problems when it has line breaks in it.